# Can I change the direction of the qt Qcombobox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I hope the drop-down list is always below the selection window.
However, it seems that the window is automatically adjusted.
The drop-down list goes up and is truncated.
I'm wondering how you can sort underneath without automatically sorting the list.

This is the situation now:

```
ex) ------------------               -------------------
    |    A        | ↓ |     ->      |         A         |
    -------------------             --------------------
                                    |         B         |
                                    ---------------------
                                    |         C         |
                                    --------------------
    C click ->
                                     -------------------
                                     |        A         |
                                     --------------------
                                     |        B         |
    -------------------              --------------------
    |    C         | ↓ |     ->      |        C         |
    -------------------              --------------------
```

But I want:

```
   ----------------------      ->    -------------------
  |           C   |  ↓  |            |        A        |
  -----------------------            -------------------
                                     |        B        |
                                      ------------------
                                     |        C        |
                                     -------------------
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the popup after it is displayed, for this you must move the internal QFrame that is the parent of the `view()` as I show below:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ComboBox(QComboBox):
    def showPopup(self):
        QComboBox.showPopup(self)
        self.view().parent().move(self.mapToGlobal(QPoint()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QMainWindow()
    cw = QWidget()
    lay = QVBoxLayout(cw)

    view = ComboBox()
    view.addItems(["A", "B", "C"])

    lay.addWidget(view)
    lay.addWidget(QTableWidget())
    w.setCentralWidget(cw)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @semikim 
if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour], that's the best way to thank :)